# Recover files from a USB that was used as a Windows 10 bootable flash drive?

Tags: windows, boot, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I used a USB flash drive that had about 59/64GB worth of files on it to make a bootable USB device for a fresh Windows 10 install on a new PC. Halfway through the validation it occurred to me that I had formatted/written over the 59GB of contents... I have mild knowledge of Scalpel/Foremost/Photorec on Unix for CTF-style file recovery questions but I don't have access to a Linux/Unix machine that will have enough space for dd-ing the whole drive. The person whose stuff I wrote over only asked for the names of the files from the drive back, and all files were InDesign documents, JPEGs, and PDFs.

I ran EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard and `chkdsk :X /f`. The EaseUS returned just the files from the Windows 10 boot and `chkdsk /f` did nothing. I have not changed the data in the image in any way.

**My question is**: will I even be able to/is it worth the effort to recover just the file names from my situation above?

Comment: How big was the windows 10 ISO? And if it has been overwritten, then there nothing you can do.

Comment: Often in this kind of situation, scavenging the files may produce some results, but getting the names back is the tough part.

Comment: A free utility, Recuva, may help you out